# Iterate through files to get the form id for google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a bunch of form files that I want to access with the FormResponse
Class. I have manage to iterate through all files as show in the code 
here:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('abcdefgh123456');
var files = folder.getFiles();

  while ( files.hasNext() ) {
  var str = files.next().getName(); 

  if (/^Approval\sfor/.test(str)) {  // test "Approval for" string 

    Logger.log('*** This is Approval file : ' + str); 
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    Logger.log('*** fileID : ' + fileId);
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId); 

    // var form = FormApp.openById(fileId);  //ERROR Invalid ID   
  }  
}
```

But for the life of me, I am not able to access the form object. I am sure it is a simple answer. Maybe my concepts is still not strong yet. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found the solution. It seems the reason I could
not access the form object is due to the mismatch of id with
file itself. The statement "var file = files.next();" should
be added under "while ( files.hasNext() )".

```
while ( files.hasNext() ) {

  var file = files.next(); 
  var str = file.getName();

  if (/^Approval\sfor/.test(str)) {  // test "Approval for" string 

   Logger.log('*** This is Approval file : ' + str); 
   var fileId = file.getId();
   Logger.log('*** fileID : ' + fileId);
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId); 
   var form = FormApp.openById(fileId);  //Works now

  }  

}
```